# Jquery - compare passwords with keyup event won't work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to compare 2 passwords fields and show something if they match or don't. My html so far:

```
<div class="row top-25">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><?php echo __('New Password', "KleeiaDev"); ?></p>
        <p><input id="pass1" type="password" value="" class="form-control info-input" name="password" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><?php echo __('Repeat Password', "KleeiaDev"); ?>:</p>
        <p><input id="pass2" type="password" value="" class="form-control info-input" name="reppassword" /></p>
        <div id="match"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery with `keyup`

```
$('#pass1, #pass2').on('keyup', function(event) {
    var pass1 = $('input[name=password]').val();
    var pass2 = $('input[name=reppassword]').val();
    if(($('input[name=password]').val().length == 0) || ($('input[name=reppassword]').val().length == 0)){
        $('#match').css({
            width:'100%',
            background: '#FFA0A0',
            border: '1px solid #FFA0A0'
        }).text("Please insert your password twice.");
    } 
    else if(pass1 != pass2){
        $('#match').css({
            width:'100%',
            background: '#FFA0A0',
            border: '1px solid #FFA0A0'
        }).text("Mmm... Passwords don't match.");
    } else {
        $('#match').css({
            width:'100%',
            background: '#C3FF88',
            border: '1px solid #C3FF88'
        }).text("Great!");
    }
});
```

Problem is that only the first sentence is shown "Please insert your password twice.". I guess it doesn't see the value's change when typing. A little help?

Comment: why not check `pass1.length == 0 || pass2.length == 0`

Comment: thanks @godmode but the other 2 else if and else won't work!

Comment: have you tried using `console.log(pass1, pass2)` to just see if there are actually values?

Comment: Work just fine... https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/23157/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I see! I suppose there is some conflicts with some jQuery plugin. i'm using strength.js on the first input. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: is there any message in your browser console?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki nope There are only input values. I'm not understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other users passing by, the previous code it's working! Problem was that I'm using a password strength checker plugin which creates a hidden `input` on the first password field (pass1). Something like:

```
<input id="pass1" type="password" class="form-control info-input strength" name="password" data-password="pass1">
<!--This is the input guilty-->
<input style="display:none" class="strength form-control info-input" data-password="pass1" type="text" name="" value="">
<input id="pass2" type="password" class="form-control info-input" name="rep password">
```

I've just changed

```
 var pass1 = $('input[name=password]').val();
```

in

```
 var pass1 = $('input.strength').val();
```

and it worked. Just for sharing, this is the [plugin](http://jquerycards.com/forms/inputs/strength-js/).